# Need to exclude string(s) during a do while loop in bash

Tags: bash, do-while

I have 2 files, that list this list when you cat them

```
cat repoExcludeList.txt: 
my-remote
pac-man

cat repoFullList.txt: 
d-main
sm-bus
csi-miami
under-auto
extra-service
B-ves
my-remote
pac-man
```

I am trying to loop via BASH through the $REPO_FULL_LIST and list each string, and ignore/exclude the lines in the $REPO_EXCLUSION_LIST

This is what I have so far, but i get this error message

```
./check_rel_branch.sh: line 13: [: my-remote: integer expression expected

REPO_FULL_LIST=`cat /path/repoFullList.txt`
REPO_EXCLUSION_LIST=`cat /path/repoExcludeList.txt`

for repo in $REPO_FULL_LIST
        do
        if [[ $repo -ne $REPO_EXCLUSION_LIST ]]; then
        echo "The repo name is $repo and will be processed"
        else
         echo "this repo will be excluded + $REPO_EXCLUSION_LIST"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing your script with:

```
echo "These will be processed:"
grep -vFf /path/repoExcludeList.txt /path/repoFullList.txt
echo ""
echo "These will be excluded:"
grep -Ff /path/repoExcludeList.txt /path/repoFullList.txt
```

The output is:

```
These will be processed:
d-main
sm-bus
csi-miami
under-auto
extra-service
B-ves

These will be excluded:
my-remote
pac-man
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some mixed syntax from `[]` style tests in the `[[]]` bash style tests you are using. I changed the script to use the return value of `grep` which can traverse the entire file list searching for a match:

```
#!/bin/bash

REPO_FULL_LIST="/path/repoFullList.txt"

REPO_EXCLUSION_LIST="/path/repoExcludeList.txt"


while read -r repo
do
    if grep "$repo" "$REPO_EXCLUSION_LIST"
    then printf "The repo name is $repo and will be processed\n"
    else printf "this repo will be excluded + $REPO_EXCLUSION_LIST\n"
    fi
done < "$REPO_FULL_LIST"
```

`grep` also supports using a file containing a list of patterns with `-f FILE, --file=FILE`